# I can't get my page to load with HTTP (instead of HTTPS)

Tags: .htaccess, http, ssl, mod-rewrite, https

I have a website that's using HTTPS.

But now I'm trying to install WordPress in a subdirectory and I temporarily need to install it HTTP (because I'm migrating a non-SSL site).

I've put a `.htaccess` file into that subdirectory, and I've tried a few rewrite commands to get the install PHP file to load with HTTP, but it keeps loading HTTPS.

I've tried the following (and variations of it):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Am I doing something wrong or could something else be forcing the HTTPS?

Comment: You shouldn't need to redirect from HTTPS to HTTP in order to correct this. If anything you would only need to add an _exception_ so the redirect to HTTPS does not happen in the first place. But yes, "something else" could be forcing HTTPS. Either another `.htaccess` or server config, or even your browser. We would need to see any additional server config files.